# Using a while loop to calculate the factorial of user input

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop, factorial

I'm trying to make while loop that calculates the factorial of user's input number. But now my program takes the factorial of the first input number and uses that result when calculating the next factorials. Any ideas on how to fix it?

This is what I have so far:

```
factorial=1
n=1
while True:
    num=int(input("Enter number: "))
    if num<=0:
        print("Thank you!")
        break
    while n<num:
        n+=1
        factorial*=n
    print(factorial)
```

Answer (score 2):

`factorial` and `n` values are not reset to their default values in your loop. They store the values of previous iteration and use them in the current iteration.

You must include the `factorial` and `n` inside the `while` loop

```
while True:
    n = 1
    factorial = 1
    num=int(input("Enter number: "))
    if num<=0:
        print("Thank you!")
        break
    while n<num:
        n+=1
        factorial*=n
    print(factorial)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, but keeping your code same, you need to reset the values of `factorial` and `n`

```py
factorial=1
n=1
while True:
    num=int(input("Enter number: "))
    if num<=0:
        print("Thank you!")
        break
    while n<num:
        n+=1
        factorial*=n
    print(factorial)
    # reset the values------------->>
    factorial=1
    n=1
```